# adding onclick to an array of items

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I have this problem where if I click on an item, all the items in that column gets affected by the click. I want only that very item where I clicked to have the class. but in my code, all the other items of that column are getting the class when I click on a certain single item. I want to make a div go fullscreen when I click on that particular div. kinda like modal pop up, here I want that the div slowly animates to fullscreen

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.addActiveClass = this.addActiveClass.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      activeIndex: -1
    };
  }
  addActiveClass(activeIndex) {
    this.setState(prev => ({
      activeIndex: prev.activeIndex === activeIndex ? -1 : activeIndex
    }));
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container">
        {Array.from({ length: 30 }).map((item, index) => {
          return (
            <div
              key={index}
              style={{
                background: randomColor(colors),
                height: randomHeight(100, 200)
              }}
              className={this.state.activeIndex === index ? "full" : ""}
              onClick={() => this.addActiveClass(index)}
            />
          );
        })}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 40px;
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #444;
  font: 2em Sansita, sans-serif;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  max-height: 100vh;
}

.container > * {
  border: 2px solid orange;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  background-color: red;
  color: #fff;
}

.full{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transition: 2s;
}
```

[sandbox demonstrating the problem](https://codesandbox.io/s/red-mountain-z8dcq)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly what kind of effect you would like to achieve with the selected item but items in the column are affected because of the default value of flexbox `align-items` which is `stretch`. The other items are stretching to match the selected element. Try to add `align-items: flex-start` to your `.container` class.

Comment: I want to make the tile resize to full screen. I did add align-items: flex-start but  now the layout doesn't look like masonry layout anymore. however it does now scale the item that i click on. can you have a look at the sandbox as to why the masonry layout isn't working out now

Comment: the width of the tiles are very small now

Comment: @helpmepiliizz It should resize to full screen on top of the other items or in some other way? Could give me some kind of visual example of the effect?

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to make sure you're adding the class to the event target. Your onClick function needs to take the event as one of it's arguments, and you need to use event.target in the function body to make sure you're only affecting the element that is clicked. Hope that makes sense!

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target

Answer (score 0):

The class adding logic works ok. You can observe this by checking the elements on developer tools. The problem is you are adding an inline style to your elements.

```
style={{
  background: randomColor(colors),
  height: randomHeight(100, 200)
}}
```

So, after each new render, this overrides the `full` class and give new height and new color.

The other problem is your `full` class. You are using `100%` for `height` and `width` and probably this causes problems for your `flex`.

Just remove the inline `style` part and instead of using a percentage give custom `width` and `height` to `full` class, then you can see adding the class logic works well.

Comment: I gave the inline style so that the divs have random height and color. how do I achieve that without adding the inline style. I'm kinda new so i'm having problems

Comment: I want a masonry layout that generates tiles with random height and color and i want to make those tiles go fullscreen on clicking and toggle back to whatever random height it gets after clicking on that tile again

Comment: Well, you can ask a different question about this issue. Because it is a different subject.

Answer (score 0):

Pass down an event `(e)` from your `onClick`, then access that specific item through `e.target.className`. This way only the clicked item is updated, even if dynamically rendered from an array:

```
handleClick = e => { e.target.classNamme = 'class' }

<div className='' onClick={e => handleClick(e)}></div>
```

Alternatively, if you're keeping your classes in the state, you can just replace the string value with your variable and control in inside the function, as you've done in the example you've provided.

Answer (score 0):

Adding `!important` overrides the inline-style height.

Height is set to 100vh to expand the div into full screen.

```
.full{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh !important;
  transition: 2s;
}
```